# Is there any built-in support for Ruby motions and text objects in Spacemacs?

Tags: ruby, vim, spacemacs, evil-mode

There're some handy Ruby motions and text objects defined in [vim-ruby](https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby/blob/074200ffa39b19baf9d9750d399d53d97f21ee07/doc/vim-ruby.txt#L10-L61) like `]m` (motion moving to the next method) or `am` (text object for a method).

Is there any built-in support for those in Spacemacs?

If not, how do I configure those in the Spacemacs way?

Answer (score 1):

There is not.

text-objects in Evil are defined as regular expressions.  There is an [open ticket](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/1182) to implement motion based text-objects but I am afraid it has gone nowhere.